# Inverse of Global Average Pooling?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, keras, convolution, pooling

I am working with a project where I want to upsample some parameters to create an electrical signal

`(shape: input=(3) output=(50,19))`

The first part of my project was to predict the parameters using the electrical signal. At that moment, the global average pooling worked really well. I wanted to know if you are aware of construction that could be the inverse of Global Average Pooling. Similarly to upsampling which is used in the decoder as the closest "inverse" of max-pooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Global Meanpooling is:

$$h = \frac{\sum^p x_i}{p}$$

It's adjoint is
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{p}$$

A constant array.
So, an operation based on that adjoint inverts, in a sense, the Global Meanpooling.
If you have a scalar $y$, the resulting activation $\mathbf g$ (a vector in the 1D case) is:

$$\mathbf g = \frac{\mathbf 1}{p}y$$

This is exactly nearest neighbor upsampling.
In the case of global pooling, you upsample based on a single value, so you arrive at a constant $\mathbf g$.

A similar argument is used to derive Transposed Convolution layers, which are defined as the adjoint of Convolution layers.